# How can I have LTspice display more digits with .op command?

Tags: ltspice

The following is the circuit in LTspice.

[image]

The following results only show 3 digits.

```
                        --- MOSFET Transistors ---
Name:          m1
Model:       nmos-sh
Id:          1.91e-04
Vgs:         7.96e-01
Vds:         9.03e-01
Vbs:         0.00e+00
Vth:         4.00e-01
Vdsat:       3.96e-01
Gm:          9.61e-04
Gds:         1.75e-05
Gmb:         0.00e+00
Cbd:         0.00e+00
Cbs:         0.00e+00
Cgsov:       0.00e+00
Cgdov:       0.00e+00
Cgbov:       0.00e+00
Cgs:         0.00e+00
Cgd:         0.00e+00
Cgb:         0.00e+00
```

How can I make them display more than 3 digits?

Comment: I remember asking Mike Engelhardt this exact same question back when he was in charge of writing the software. I’ll try to dig up the email but it was basically “You can’t, and who cares.”

Comment: @SteKulov Do you mean there is no way now?

Comment: Correct.  I found the email.  I'll post an answer with more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, just to clarify your question, you're not talking about normal `.op` output of voltages and currents.  You're talking about the calculated small-signal parameters for non-linear semiconductor devices that are spit out in the SPICE Error Log <kbd>CTRL+L</kbd> after a `.op` analysis.

Anyway, I asked this same exact question to the then-author of LTspice (Mike Engelhardt) back in August 2018.  Below is a copy/paste of my  question and his answer.

**QUESTION**

> Hello.  I was wondering if there's a way to get more significant digits when looking at the linearized small-signal parameters in the
> error log after a DC operating point analysis.  Example output is
> below:
>
> ```
> Direct Newton iteration for .op point succeeded.
> Semiconductor Device Operating Points:
>                         --- Diodes ---
> Name:      d1
> Model:   1n4148
> Id:      8.25e-03
> Vd:      6.84e-01
> Req:     5.49e+00
> CAP:     3.65e-09
> ```
>
> I tried changing a few of the significant digit items in the .options
> but that didn't affect this output.  Is this controlled via a separate
> command?
>
> Thanks!

**ANSWER**

> There's no adjustment available.  BTW, I've never seen a semiconductor
> model with three digit accuracy, either.

TRANSLATION: No, there is no way to do this, but it shouldn't matter since the model parameters which are inputs to these calculations never have an accuracy higher than three digits to begin with.